# S3 + Cloudfront + Route53 - HTTPS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have an issue with "https" for my site. I bought the certificate through COMODO, and i have imported it into AWS. When i access my site in the browser, the "https", doesn't appear. It remains at "http".

Here is a photo from my ACM, where it says the certificate is valid.

[image]

Below are 2 pictures with the settings from the Cloudfront disribution:

1. General Settings - where i have chosen my certificate

[image]

2. Behaviour Settings - where i have my S3 bucket selected and redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

[image]

These are the Route53 settings:

[image]

Can you please tell me what i am missing? Where i did or didn't do something?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try to access https: //yourwebsite.com ?

Comment: I am being redirected to **http://**  www.example.com/. This is strange. Yesterday, when i tried loading the site with **https**, it didn't load. Now i am being redirected to "http". It should have been the other way around.

Comment: If i try to enter the site like **https://** www.examle.com/ , it doesn't load. Without ***www*** is being redirected to "http", and with "www" is not loading.

Comment: Can you show me/us your route53 config

Comment: i have added the image from route53, into the description above.

Comment: Please do check this : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/ and especially step 3, I don't see any CNAME record here in your image

Comment: can you please show me what do i need to write when i create a new Record Set for CNAME? An image would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to add something like this in route53 (sorry, unable to upload an image as I am on mobile)

www.yoursite.com CNAME https:// asdf1234.cloudfront.net/ 
More info here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html